# Choiche GPU tensorflow-directml or multi-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, amd-gpu

I'm training a model with TensorFlow on a Windows PC, but the training is slow so I'm trying to configure TensorFlow to use a GPU.
I installed `tensorflow-directml` (in a Conda environment with Python 3.6) because my GPU is an AMD Radeon GPU.
With this simple code

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

I receive this output

```
2021-05-14 11:02:30.113880: I
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports
instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2021-05-14 11:02:30.121580: I
tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:99]
Successfully opened dynamic library
C:\Users\v.rocca\anaconda3\envs\tfradeon\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python/directml.adbd007a01a52364381a1c71ebb6fa1b2389c88d.dll
2021-05-14 11:02:30.765470: I
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/dml/dml_device_cache.cc:249] DirectML
device enumeration: found 2 compatible adapters. 2021-05-14
11:02:30.984834: I
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/dml/dml_device_cache.cc:185] DirectML:
creating device on adapter 0 (Radeon (TM) 530) 2021-05-14
11:02:31.150992: I
tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:99]
Successfully opened dynamic library Kernel32.dll 2021-05-14
11:02:31.174716: I
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/dml/dml_device_cache.cc:185] DirectML:
creating device on adapter 1 (Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620) True
```

So tensorflow get the integrated GPU Intel instead the Radeon GPU.
If I disable the Intel GPU from the Manage Hardware I receive in the output the correct GPU

```
2021-05-14 10:47:09.171568: I
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports
instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2021-05-14 10:47:09.176828: I
tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:99]
Successfully opened dynamic library
C:\Users\v.rocca\anaconda3\envs\tfradeon\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python/directml.adbd007a01a52364381a1c71ebb6fa1b2389c88d.dll
2021-05-14 10:47:09.421265: I
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/dml/dml_device_cache.cc:249] DirectML
device enumeration: found 1 compatible adapters. 2021-05-14
10:47:09.626567: I
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/dml/dml_device_cache.cc:185] DirectML:
creating device on adapter 0 (Radeon (TM) 530)
```

I don't want to disable the Intel GPU every time so this is my question.
Is it possible to choice which GPU I want to use? Or Is it possible to use both GPUs?
Thanks

Comment: Don't know if it works for `tensorflow-direcml`, but I'd suggest `tf.config.set_visible_devices`

Comment: Yes, set_visible_devices is in tf.config.experimental, but with `tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices()` I can't see my physical GPUs, the result is `[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:DML:0', device_type='DML')]`. I think the GPU is abstracted by the DML device so I can't pass the radeon GPU in set_visible_device

Answer (score 0):

From [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/gpu-faq):

```
gpu_config = tf.GPUOptions()
gpu_config.visible_device_list = "1"

session = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_config))
```

Comment: With this commands it seems the gpu is changed but the output give me this error `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.AlreadyExistsError: TensorFlow device (DML:0) is being mapped to multiple DML devices (0 now, and 1 previously), which is not supported. This may be the result of providing different GPU configurations (ConfigProto.gpu_options, for example different visible_device_list) when creating multiple Sessions in the same process. This is not  currently supported, see https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19083`